# When i run this code the counter only goes 1 and 2 but i want to make it go 5

Tags: php, sql

When  i run this php  code the counter variable only goes 1 and 2 but i want to make it go 5 what is wrong here anyone can help me ? why the counter dosent go up from 2 ?

```
<?php
session_start();
include "sql.php";
$date = $_POST['date'];
$email = $_SESSION[email];
$counter = 0;
$check = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num = 1){

    $data = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
    $dresult = mysqli_query($con, $data);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($dresult); 

    $counter = $row[counter];
    echo $counter;
    if ($counter < 5){

        $counter=$counter+1;
        $reg= "insert into reservations(date,counter,email) values('$date' , '$counter' , '$email')";
        mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    }

    else{

        echo "no tables available";
    }

}
else{

    $data = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
    $dresult = mysqli_query($con, $data);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($dresult);
    $counter = $row[counter];

    $counter=$counter+1;
    $reg= "insert into reservations(date,counter,email) values('$date' , '$counter' , '$email')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
}
```

Comment: what you get in $counter; variable?

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Where did you define `counter`?

Comment: you need a `loop`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put it on a looping.
Check code below:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "sql.php";
$date = $_POST['date'];
$email = $_SESSION[email];
$counter = 0;
$check = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $check);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num = 1){

    $data = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
    $dresult = mysqli_query($con, $data);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($dresult); 

    $counter = $row[counter];
    echo $counter;
    if ($counter < 5){
      while($counter <= 5){

        //$counter=$counter+1;
        $reg= "insert into reservations(date,counter,email) values('$date' , '$counter' , '$email')";
        mysqli_query($con, $reg);
       $counter++;

      }
    }

    else{

        echo "no tables available";
    }

}
else{

    $data = " select * from reservations where date = '$date'";
    $dresult = mysqli_query($con, $data);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($dresult);
    $counter = $row[counter];

    $counter=$counter+1;
    $reg= "insert into reservations(date,counter,email) values('$date' , '$counter' , '$email')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
}
```